# Can you explain me what this method does?

Tags: c#

We found this method in a book.

From what I understand wants to check if a number is ordered ascending.

For example, the number 54321 (all figures have ordered ascending)

However, I do not understand how this method works ... why returns 0 or 1?

Can you explain to me in a simple way what happens in this method?

```
 static int f(long n)
    {
        while(n>10)
        {
            if (n % 10 > n / 10 % 10) return 0;
            n = n / 10;


        }
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Hint: what does the value `n % 10` represent? What does the value `n / 10 % 10` represent? What does the value `n / 10` represent? (BTW, in the number 54321, the digits are descending, not ascending.)

Comment: Why don't you try and see?

Comment: Still, I wonder what the author's reason was to not have returned a boolean

Comment: N is a number type to greater than 10

Comment: N is inserted in a textblock

Comment: What specifically don't you understand? The `%` operator, the `if`, or something else? If you make a break down for yourself you should be able to figure out what it does.

Comment: I do not understand the IF condition. What happens in this instruction?

Comment: Did you try insert a value and set a break point to see what happens?

Comment: Add `Console.WriteLine` debug statements for the sections you dont understand and see the output.

Comment: @dcastro On first guess, I would think that the author returns 1, and 0, because that is how it was done in C++.   0 is false and not 0 is true.  It's not really useful in C#, but someone thinking that it works like C would make that assumption.

Comment: It says, as long as `n` is positive and has at least two digits, check if the last digit `n % 10` is greater than the second-to-last digit `(n / 10) % 10`, and return `0` in that case.

Comment: @Kevin But an author of a book would surely know the first thing about the language he's using.

Comment: @dcastro: Indeed. And if he does not, you should stop reading that book.

Comment: @dcastro That is a strong assumption.  I've worked with too many people in the technical writing process to ever think that again.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen `n >= 10` tests that `n` has at least two digits. `n > 10` does not.

Comment: @hvd True. They could have said `n >= 12` really, because we easily see that `10` and `11` are non-increasing sequences of digits. I do not take responsibility for the ugly code.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Right. `n >= 10` would have made sense to me, for readability. `n >= 12` would have made sense to me as a quick (and probably unnecessary) optimisation. `n >= 11` (or equivalently, `n > 10`) does not really make all that much sense to me.

Comment: A quick read of the C# documentation might help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can be explained by simply walking through the code with a debugger or a piece of paper. As such, it displays no attempt to solve this, it is unclear where the confusion lies and provides no value to future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n % 10` gets you the digit in the unit's place and `n / 10 % 10` gets you the digit in the ten's place.

The author is comparing these two digits and returning `0` if the digit in the unit's place is larger than the one in the ten's place.

If not, he is dividing n by 10 to discard the number in the unit's place. Now, the number that was in the ten's place is now in the unit's place and the one in the hundred's place is now in the ten's place and the previous steps are repeated.

If the number becomes less than or equal to 10 after you keep discarding the last number, if it hasn't returned 0, it will return 1, which suggests that all the digits in `n` are in descending order from left to right.